# How do I make a view showing selected id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know how to show all data from db using foreach but do not know how to show only 1 record that I select.

My code:

```
public function go($id)//controller
{
    $data["log"] = $this->product_model->getAll();   
    $data['id']=$id;
    $this->load->view("admin/kampus/list1",$data);
}
public function getById($id)//modal
{
    return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["ID" => $id])->row();
}

//view
<?php foreach ($log as $product): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product->ID ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product->TGL_MULAI ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product->KETERANGAN ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please help me to show one record using foreach.

Comment: @ropfoyle thanks for edit

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the `foreach`.

Or, change `row()` to `result()`.

Comment: and replace foreach with what ? thats i dont know what to write :)

Comment: you don't need to replace it with anything. you remove it entirely, as your dataset with `row()` isn't an array of objects!

Answer (score 0):

foreach operate on arrays and to show single record you should send it to view as array of objects. To do this just replace `$data["log"]` with `$data["log"][]` when you get single record from db. Check below code

```
public function go($id)//controller
{
$data["log"][] = $this->product_model->getById($id);   
$data['id']=$id;
$this->load->view("admin/kampus/list1",$data);
}
public function getById($id)//modal
{
return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["ID" => $id])->row();
}

//view
<?php foreach ($log as $product): ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php echo $product->ID ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $product->TGL_MULAI ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $product->KETERANGAN ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i am sorry for not understand , and what thing i fill to blank array ?

Comment: the record returned from model will be placed to the $data["log"][] array. and array will not be blank.

Comment: just give it a try it will work . you can also check that array is not empty before foreach in your view

Answer (score 0):

You should remove foreach and  do this

```
 return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["ID" => $id])->row_Array();
```

than you can use this

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product['id'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product->['tg_mulai'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product->['keterangan'] ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

you can use `foreach()` for only multiple rows

Comment: I got this syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' , and thanks for your answer

Comment: try this return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, array("ID" => $id))->row_Array();

Answer (score 0):

**First view, where you click to see selected data**

```
<?php foreach ($log as $product): ?>
<a href="<?= base_url('controller/function/').$product->id; ?>" 
class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Then Controller will receive the id like**

```
public function edit_product($id){
    $data['datas'] = $this->your_model->model_function($id);
    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function model_function($id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->from('table_name');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Single Data View**

```
<?php foreach($datas as $data): ?>
    <?php echo $data->id; ?>
    <?php echo $data->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Let me know if it's ok**

Comment: wait wait , i will try later bro , thanks a lot , i will tell you next time if its ok

Comment: that not answer for my problem , i just want to show 1 data that selected by the id , just like delete , delete is commonly depent on id right ? thats what i want to know